# C++ & PyQt | User Defined Slot and Connect for QCheckBox

Tags: c++, pyqt

I want to implement an user defined slot that passes the sender object as an argument in addition for the check boxes in my dialog.

I have tried the following:

slots:

```
public slots:
    void updateUI(int, QCheckBox *sender);
```

connect:

```
connect(this->allLayersetsCheckBox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(updateUI(int, QCheckBox*)));
connect(this->selectedLayersetsCheckBox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(updateUI(int, QCheckBox*)));
connect(this->unselectedLayersetsCheckBox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(updateUI(int, QCheckBox*)));
```

method:

```
void MyDialog::updateUI(int state, QCheckBox *sender) {
    cout << "updateUI" << endl;
    cout << qPrintable( sender->text() ) << endl;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
            QCheckBox::stateChanged(int) --> MyDialog::updateUI(int,QCheckBox*) QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
            QCheckBox::stateChanged(int) --> MyDialog::updateUI(int,QCheckBox*) QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
            QCheckBox::stateChanged(int) --> MyDialog::updateUI(int,QCheckBox*)
```

Is this not possible?
Or how would one implement this?

I would really like to know which CheckBox is calling the updateUI method.
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what object sent a signal, then just use [QObject::sender](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) in the receiving slot. That'll give you a QObject pointer, which you can try to dynamic_cast to the appropriate type.